# Set instanceTree to a custom node in Forge 3D viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Lets say I'm working with a 3D file which is the combination of one Architectural model and one Structural model.
The instance tree or Model Browser looks like this

```
root/
    Arch/
        Level 01/
        Level 02/
        ...
    Str/
        Level 01/
        Level 02/
        ...
```

I want to display only the Level 01.
So I:

1. Followed the steps in the Viewer tutorial
2. Add an event listener to both `Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` & `Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT`
3. When the 2 are fired, I use the code in this [article](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/hidding-completely-viewer-nodes-no-ghosting) to display only the Level 01 without ghosting.

I have 2 problem with this approach

1. I have to wait until the entire model is loaded before I can filter the level
2. After filtering the level, if I click on Model Browser, I can still see the entire model structure (but with everything as hidden except Level 01). How can I set the instance tree to only have what's below?

   ```
   root/
       Arch/
          Level 01/
       Str/
          Level 01/
   ```

**EDIT**
At what point am I supposed to override the `shouldInclude()` function?
I've tried this and put a breakpoint but it seems it never gets called... I also tried to move it around but in vain.

```
const start = Date.now();
Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ModelStructurePanel.shouldInclude = (node) => {
  Logger.log(node);
  return true;
};
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
  Logger.log(`Viewer initialized in ${Date.now() - start}ms`);
  const config = {};
  // prettier-ignore
  Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('MyAwesomeExtension', MyAwesomeExtension);
  viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('MyViewerDiv');
  viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D, config);
  loadDocumentStart = Date.now();
  // prettier-ignore
  viewerApp.loadDocument(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wasn't able to understand how to use `ModelStructurePanel`, I overrode `Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication.selectItem` to only modify the `options` which are either passed to `loadDocumentNode` or `startWithDocumentNode` as below:

```
const options = {
    ids: leafIDs.length > 0 ? leafIDs : null, // changed this line
    acmSessionId: this.myDocument.acmSessionId,
    loadOptions,
    useConsolidation: this.options.useConsolidation,
    consolidationMemoryLimit: this.options.consolidationMemoryLimit || 100 * 1024 * 1024, // 100 MB
  };
```

With `leafIDs` being an array of objectIDs to display. I was able to build it by:

1. querying the ModelDerivativeAPI using `GET   :urn/metadata/:guid`
2. going through the tree to find the ids which I am interested in.

There's probably a more elegant way to do this but that's the best I could do so far.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding #1: the object tree is stored in the file's internal database which - for performance reasons - is only loaded *after* the actual geometry.

Regarding #2: you can subclass the [ModelStructurePanel](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/modelstructurepanel) class and add your own behavior, for example, by overriding the [ModelStructurePanel#shouldInclude](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/modelstructurepanel/#shouldinclude-node) method.

Comment: I see, so the solution is to get the model structure via the Model Derivative API as described here [link](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/get-all-dbid-without-enumerating-model-hierarchy) and then override the shouldInclude method.

Comment: Yep, I think this approach should cover your use case. Cheers!